# Cannot Authorize my Service Account to use the Domain Shared contacts API

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-shared-contacts

I'm trying to impersonate a super admin account to use the shared contacts API to create new contacts in a directory, after using the gdata client library I couldn't authorize my request even tho I used the same method I used to authorize another API call but for the Directory API instead of the Domain Shared Contacts.

Here is my code:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gdata.contacts
import gdata.contacts.data
import gdata.contacts.client
import atom

class TestView(APIView):

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = (
        "x-serviceaccount@x.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    )
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Hoda\\Desktop\\xtools\\x\\Backend\\x-x.p12"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
            self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH,
            "notasecret",
            scopes=[
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
                'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'
            ],
        )

        gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient()
        credentials = credentials.create_delegated('admin@admin.com')
        service = build('admin', 'something', credentials=credentials) 
        #while using the directory API I wrote directory_v1 instead of 
        #something and now I have no 
        #idea what to write and is that even the right way to authorize 
        #the service account here or not

        new_contact = gdata.contacts.data.ContactEntry()
        new_contact.name = gdata.data.Name(
            given_name=gdata.data.GivenName(text="Mohamed"),
            family_name=gdata.data.FamilyName(text="Safi"),
            full_name=gdata.data.FullName(text="Mohamed Safi"),
        )
        new_contact.content = atom.data.Content(text="Notes")
        new_contact.email.append(
            gdata.data.Email(
                address="liz@gmail.com",
                primary="true",
                rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL,
                display_name="E. Bennet",
            )
        )
        new_contact.email.append(
            gdata.data.Email(address="liz@example.com", rel=gdata.data.HOME_REL)
        )
        new_contact.phone_number.append(
            gdata.data.PhoneNumber(
                text="(206)555-1212", rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL, primary="true"
            )
        )
        new_contact.phone_number.append(
            gdata.data.PhoneNumber(text="(206)555-1213", rel=gdata.data.HOME_REL)
        )
        new_contact.im.append(
            gdata.data.Im(
                text="liz@gmail.com",
                primary="true",
                rel=gdata.data.HOME_REL,
                protocol=gdata.data.GOOGLE_TALK_PROTOCOL,
            )
        )
        new_contact.structured_postal_address.append(
            gdata.data.PostalAddress(
            rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL,
            primary="true",
            street=gdata.data.Street(text="1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"),
            city=gdata.data.City(text="Mountain View"),
            region=gdata.data.Region(text="CA"),
            postcode=gdata.data.Postcode(text="94043"),
            country=gdata.data.Country(text="United States"),)
        )
        contact_entry = gd_client.create_contact(new_contact) 
        print("Contact's ID: %s" % contact_entry.id.text)
        return Response(contact_entry)
```

So, now I just want to know how to authorize that service account to write data into my directory.

side note: I have given the service account all the authorization needed in my admin console.

Comment: Are there any error codes or identifiers as to where the authorization is failing? Maybe we can start from there

Comment: no there aren't any errors in my code, just not authorized to create a user. 403 error that is what I get

Comment: if only there is a way to know what is the service name and version to use the `build` function from `googleapiclient.discovery`, I think that will solve the issue

Comment: It might be best if you could read through this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using the discovery `build` function is not the right way to call the `create_contact()` function which is associated with the domain shared contacts API. What I found out is that I can authorize my service account using the `gauth` module which lies inside the `gdata` library, you can `import` it as follows:

```
import gdata.gauth
```

after that,

1. you create your service account credentials the same way as shown in
   the question code.
2. use the `OAuth2TokenFromCredentials` class which lies inside the
   `gauth` module  to provide a way for you to use OAuth 2.0
   credentials obtained for use with google-api-python-client as
   credentials in gdata-python-client, you can use it as follows:
   `auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)`

> credentials in the code above refer to the credentials you just created using
> your service
> account email and key file.

3. authorize your gdata client `gd_client = auth2token.authorize(gd_client)`

then after that, congrats you can use your gdata client to make authorized requests with your service account impersonating any admin at any workspace.